# Add a non-repeatable line inside a foreach/switch

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, switch-statement

I have this loop, which shows books based in a year:

```
foreach ($cases_result as $case) {
    $i = $case->n_ano;
    switch ($i) {

        case $i >= 2013:
            echo $case->book.'<br>';
            break;

        case $i <= 2012 && $i >= 2011:
            echo $case->book.'<br>';
            break;
        case $i <= 2010 && $i >= 2009:
            echo $case->book.'<br>';
            break;
        case $i <= 2008 && $i >= 2007:
            echo $case->book.'<br>';
            break;
    }

}
```

Is possible to to add a non-repeatable line to separate each case?

I need to show the year, like so:

```
2013
 - book 1
 - book 2
2012
 - book 3
 - book 4
```

Here is an excerpt of the array:

```
array (size=22)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[14]
      public 'book' => string 'book 1' (length=6)
      public 'n_ano' => string '2013' (length=4)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[15]
      public 'book' => string 'book 2' (length=6)
      public 'n_ano' => string '2013' (length=4)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'book' => string 'book 3' (length=6)
      public 'n_ano' => string '2012' (length=4)
```

Comment: Can you post your array?

Comment: @Rob Sure. I edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First I create an array, which uses the year as key and adds the book name to the array, so you then can simply loop over it, e.g.

```
<?php

    foreach($arr as $v)
            $data[$v->n_ano][] = $v->book;

    foreach($data as $n_ano => $books) {
        echo $n_ano . "<br>";
        foreach($books as $book)
            echo " - " . $book . "<br>";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
2013
 - book 1
 - book 2
2012
 - book 3
```

Comment: Why did you tell me that my code will give me a "Strict Standards" message in another post, and post code yourself that will most likely result in PHP warnings?

Comment: I think it will because $data isn't defined as array before and neither is $data[$v->n_ano].

Comment: @Typoheads It will create an array: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying ?!

Comment: I swear I have seen warnings in case of not initializing arrays, but you are right your code works fine. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

First, sort your array by n_ano. Then you can easily loop trough the sorted result and create a grouped output.

```
function sortCases($a, $b) {
    return $a->n_ano < $b->n_ano;
}

usort($cases_result, "sortCases");

$out = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($cases_result as $case) {

    //If the year is different, print year and assign it so $i
    if($i !== intval($case->n_ano)) {
        $out .= '<h2>' . $case->n_ano . '</h2>';
        $i = intval($case->n_ano);
    }

    $out .= $case->book . '<br>';
}

print $out;
```